# Swift : Auto Text in Shinobi Grid

Tags: swift, datagrid, shinobi

I'm working with Shinobi Data Grid but i get a little problem because the Swift example or question about Shinobi Grid is very hard to find. Below my snippet code :

```
    var grid: ShinobiDataGrid?

    grid = ShinobiDataGrid(frame: self.view.bounds)
    grid?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: (screenWidth), height: 600)

    theme = SDataGridTheme()
    theme?.iOS7Arrows = true
    theme?.hideVerticalGridlines = false
    grid?.apply(theme)

    self.view.addSubview(grid!) 
    .........

   addColumn(grid!, title: "Floor", width: 100, alignment: .right, alignmentHeader: .right)

    grid?.numberOfFrozenColumns = 2
    grid?.layer.borderWidth = 1

    grid?.defaultCellStyleForHeaderRow.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#1A237E")
    grid?.defaultCellStyleForHeaderRow.textColor = UIColor.white
    grid?.defaultCellStyleForHeaderRow.font.withSize(5)

    grid?.dataSource = self
    grid?.delegate = self
    ........

   func shinobiDataGrid(_ grid: ShinobiDataGrid!, prepareCellForDisplay cell: SDataGridCell!) {
    let textCell = cell as! SDataGridTextCell

     //        let textCell = cell as! SDataGridMultiLineTextCell
    var dataRow: [AnyHashable: Any]?

    dataRow = filteredDataRoomingList?[cell.coordinate.row.rowIndex] as? [AnyHashable: Any]

    textCell.sizeToFit()

    if (searchBarActive) {
        dataRow = filteredSearchDataRoomingList?[cell.coordinate.row.rowIndex] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    }
    else {
       dataRow = filteredDataRoomingList?[cell.coordinate.row.rowIndex] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    }

    if textCell.coordinate.column.tag == 0 {
        textCell.textField.text = (String(dataRow?["floor"] as! Int))
    //            gridMultiLine.textLabel.text = (String(dataRow?["floor"] as! Int))

           }
   }
```

I want my cell show the full text inside its content(wrap content) not truncate the text with .... .

I read [this](https://forum.shinobicontrols.com/t/how-can-i-wrap-text-in-a-grid-cell/1265) but i dont have idea with this block because its in Objective C :

```
SDataGridColumn *nameColumn = [[SDataGridColumn alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forename" cellType:[SDataGridMultiLineTextCell class]];
nameColumn.editable = YES;
nameColumn.width = @250;
[self.shinobiDataGrid addColumn:nameColumn];
```

Any suggest and answer will help for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a function base of the [this](https://forum.shinobicontrols.com/t/how-can-i-wrap-text-in-a-grid-cell/1265) , below the code :

```
func addColoumn(_ grid: ShinobiDataGrid, title: String, width: CGFloat, tag: Int, alignment: NSTextAlignment) {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidthInt = screenSize.width - CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width)))

    let column = SDataGridColumn(title: title, cellType: SDataGridMultiLineTextCell.self)
    column?.width = (Int(screenWidthInt / width) as NSNumber) /*width as NSNumber!*/
    column?.tag = tag
    column?.cellStyle.textAlignment = alignment
    column?.headerCellStyle.textAlignment = alignment

    grid.addColumn(column)

}
```

And dataSource `prepareCellForDisplay` became like this :

```
func shinobiDataGrid(_ grid: ShinobiDataGrid!, prepareCellForDisplay cell: SDataGridCell!) {
    let dataCell = cell as! SDataGridMultiLineTextCell
    if cell.coordinate.column.tag == 0 {

        dataCell.sizeToFit()
        dataCell.textLabel.text = "msadimfodvnuonvosvndvdivndlvsndvmvnlcvnoidn odnosdvk odkmvosdk sodimdokvs kmdsdokv "

    }
    if cell.coordinate.column.tag == 1 {

        dataCell.sizeToFit()
        dataCell.textLabel.text = "msadimfodvnuonvosvndvdivndlvsndvmvnlcvnoidn odnosdvk odkmvosdk sodimdokvs kmdsdokv sdmfdfkm sdlfkdmlf dosfod domdso os "

    }
}
```

[image]